# MS access SQL left function not returning anything

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi im trying to create a query to only display those with the same 3 letters of a postcode, however, it returns nothing at all. This is my code:

```
SELECT Custtbl.Name, Custtbl.PostCode
FROM Custtbl
Where (((Custtbl.PostCode)=Left([PostCode],3)))
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is `[PostCode]` a parameter of this query? Or are you trying to compare the table with itself?

Comment: PostCode is in the table. Trying to compare the table with itself

Comment: Then I have no idea what your are trying to do. Please post some sample data and expected result, use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: For example, if i have a table full of customer details, i want the query to filter out the details of customers that do not share the same first 3 letters of a postcode

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description.

Comment: actual and expected data: https://gyazo.com/f25920f5f75852b0bd8c68b6d102b65a

Answer (score 1):

This is how:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Custtbl.Name, 
    Custtbl.PostCode
FROM 
    Custtbl,
    Custtbl As T
WHERE 
    Custtbl.Name <> T.Name
    AND
    Left(Custtbl.PostCode, 3) = Left(T.[PostCode], 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Left function on Custtbl.PostCode. Your query should be

```
SELECT Custtbl.Name, Custtbl.PostCode
FROM Custtbl
Where ((LEFT(Custtbl.PostCode,3)=Left([PostCode],3)))
```

Comment: Still doesnt work, just creates a new column displaying the first 3 letters of every postcode.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here, since its the same column name. I thought its a parameter. If its the same column, how can be a trimmed Postcode be equal to a complete postcode?

Comment: For example, if i have a table full of customer details, i want the query to filter out the details of customers that do not share the same first 3 letters of a postcode

Comment: It can vary, so any postcode in which the first 3 letters are used in more than one entry of customer information

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the LIKE condition. [TutorialPoint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

```
SELECT Custtbl.Name, Custtbl.PostCode
FROM Custtbl
Where (Custtbl.PostCode LIKE Left([PostCode],3) + '%')
```

This will return any row where the first 3 characters in [PostCode] match the first 3 characters in Custtbl.PostCode

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't return anything, any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure it should return data? Have you verified both tables? This is the most sure-fire way I have ever encountered to do what you're wanting to do. Double check that it actually should be returning what you're expected. Trace the data by hand.

Comment: Yeah it should do, it's all in one table and there are definitely data entries with the same 3 letters of a postcode in there. No idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Ok. Find a Post code in your table. In your query above, remove the "LEFT(PostCode,3) + '%'" and replace it with " '###%' " where ### are the first 3 numbers of the PostCode from your table. If this returns nothing, then it is not the where clause that is your issue. it's something else.

Comment: replacing it with "###%" did not return anything but replacing it with "###*" did so. Could this be the cause of my problems?

Comment: Wildcard character in Access is `*` not `%`. But then it will return all rows. Again, this question makes no sense without sample data.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f25920f5f75852b0bd8c68b6d102b65a this is the actual and expected data i am looking for